# Jquery and revslider not working in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am new on react.js and just started working on react.

1. During conversion of static HTML to react.js, jquery is only executing after refreshing the page explicitly due to which react speed is getting slow and the same thing is happening with jquery revslider.
   Have tried to write jquery in componentDidMount but still need to refresh page explicit to run jquery.
2. Even for third party jquery, facing the same problem need to refresh the page.

Full code:

index.html

```
</script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/revslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3           /jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Can also be used with $(window).load(function() 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

revslider.js

```
var revapi2,
tpj=jQuery;     
tpj(document).ready(function() {
if(tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").revolution === undefined){
    revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_2_1");
}else{
     revapi2 = tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").show().revolution({
     sliderType:"standard",
     jsFileLocation:"js/",
     sliderLayout:"fullwidth",
     dottedOverlay:"none",
     delay:3000,
     navigation: {
         keyboardNavigation:"off",
         keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
         mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
         mouseScrollReverse:"default",
         onHoverStop:"off",
     touch:{
         touchenabled:"on",
         touchOnDesktop:"off",
         swipe_threshold: 75,
         swipe_min_touches: 50,
         swipe_direction: "horizontal",
         drag_block_vertical: false
     }
     },
     visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
     gridwidth:1920,
     gridheight:1080,
     lazyType:"single",
     parallax: {
         type:"mouse",
         origo:"slidercenter",
         speed:2000,
         levels:[2,3,4,5,6,7,12,16,10,50,47,48,49,50,51,55],
         disable_onmobile:"on"
     },
     shadow:0,
     spinner:"off",
     stopLoop:"off",
     stopAfterLoops:-1,
     stopAtSlide:-1,
     shuffle:"off",
     autoHeight:"off",
     hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
     hideSliderAtLimit:0,
     hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
     hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
     debugMode:false,
     fallbacks: {
         simplifyAll:"off",
         nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
         disableFocusListener:false,
         panZoomDisableOnMobile:"on",
     }
   });
  }
});
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        sliderArrow();
        menu();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Header />
                <Head />
                <DigitalEvolution />
                <OurServiceLine />
                <SomeConcepts />
                <Last />
                <Footer />
            </Aux>
       );
   }
}
export default App;
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/'  component={App} />
    <Route exact path='/index.html' component={App}/>
    <Route exact path='/Digital-Strategies.html' component={Digital} />
    <Route exact path='/Service-Lines.html' component={ServiceLines} />
    <Route exact path='/Operations-Transformation.html'component=               {Operations}/>
    <Route exact path='/Why-us.html' component={WhyUs}/>
    <Route exact path='/Mission.html' component={Mission}/>
    <Route exact path='/Our-group.html' component={OurGroup}/>
    <Route exact path='/Team.html' component={Team}/>
    <Route exact path='/Projects.html' component={Projects}/>
    <Route exact path ='/Research-Development.html' component = {Research}/>
    <Route exact path='/News.html' component={News}/>
    <Route exact path='/Locations.html' component={Locations}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: It's usually easier for others to help if you have included a demo site like jsfiddle to demo your problem

Comment: Sorry but your question is not more urgent than the other questions here

Answer (score 0):

You can install revolution slider for react `npm i -S react-rev-slider` it works in a similar way as the HTML + jquery. 
If you want to load third party libraries to react and load them without refreshing the page, use this function

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

   let script = document.createElement("script")
   script.type = "text/javascript";

   if (script.readyState){  //IE
       script.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                   script.readyState == "complete"){
               script.onreadystatechange = null;
               callback();
           }
       };
   } else {  //Others
       script.onload = function(){
           callback();
       };
   }
```

And call it from component will mount.
PS. The callback parameter holds the next script function. That is

```
componentWillMount(){
loadScript("/js/jquery.js", ()=>{
loadScript("/js/animations.js",()=>{})
})
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution to implement revslider with React

First you import all required scripts and css for revslider in index.html in public folder

This will work for only one time when you load or refresh the page, but won't work in your case when changing routes. so the solution to this is to load the script in componentWillMount.

so your code will be like this...

in revslider_component.js file

```
    componentWillMount(){
        function loadScript(src) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            script.addEventListener('load', function () {
              resolve();
            });
            script.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
              reject(e);
            });
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            document.body.removeChild(script);
          })
        };

      loadScript('path/to/revslider/script1'); // make sure to load them in order
      loadScript('path/to/revslider/script2'); // PS. in order to import path out side your src folder and inside public folder use ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/js/revslider.js
      loadScript('path/to/revslider/script3'); 
    }
```